# Error during Python Pynini lib installation: "fatal error: 'ios' file not found"

Tags: installation, python, ios, gcc, python3

I ran the command '''python3 setup.py install''' and '''python3 setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local''' in order to install the Python package Pynini through CLI but got the following unexplained error, which I am not sure what it is due to:

```
'''[...] 
running build_ext
building 'pywrapfst' extension gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Library/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Library/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c src/pywrapfst.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/pywrapfst.o -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -funsigned-char
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
src/pywrapfst.cc:612:10: fatal error: 'ios' file not found
#include "ios"
         ^~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1'''
```

It appears that there are two errors (the iOS- and the gcc-related ones). How could I solve them ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Cross-post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397207/how-to-fix-error-during-pynini-module-installation-python-by-cli-error-messag).

Comment: Shot in the dark but try `CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++' python3 setup.py install`.

Comment: @Anaksunaman thank you so much, that turned out to work ! I had some other steps to have the module be effective after that but installation was completed subsequent to your command. Can you briefly explain what it does ? Thanks again !

Comment: You're welcome. I have added a brief answer to (hopefully) address your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++' python3 setup.py install`.

> Can you briefly explain what this command does?

On Mac OS X, `gcc` and `g++` are sometimes actually aliases for [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), not [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). `CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++'` is (as far as I am aware) a Clang-specific compiler flag that indicates Clang should use `libc++` during compilation (which is done as part of the Pynini module installation).

Regarding why this works, it appears that the header files for `stdlibc++` couldn't be found. Thus, in this instance, it is apparently necessary to tell Clang to use `libc++` instead

```
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead
```

---

*Also note that `-std=c++11` has been specified and `libc++` is a [post-C++11 implementation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/) of the [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) from the same people who produce Clang.*

---